# How to use FilterPool and Collection using the FilterApplierInterface

Tags: magento2, admin, collection, filter, data-provider

Hi fellow Magento developers!

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the FilterPool with classes instead of using it with the etc/di.xml.

It should be possible to use filters in a grid listing without setting up a di.xml virtual provider, however, I can't seem to work out how..

How I understand it now is like this:

You have a class, say `Supplier`, and you want it to be the `DataProvider` for given listing `supplier_listing.xml`, I also want to be able to apply `Filter`'s to it, therefore i'm going to implement the interface `FilterApplierInterface`, which requires me to implement a method called `apply()`.

However, the `apply()` method requires a `Collection` object and a `Filter` object, and this is where I get lost, how can I specify which data to apply and what Filter to use? Do I need to call the `apply()` method myself or should the Magento framework do this for me? If so, how can I tell Magento which Collection to use and what Filter to apply?

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm at a loss right now..

On a side note, i've used the di.xml virtual providers, however, I want to learn more about how Magento does it and how to do it yourself without the virtuals. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not exact answer but it works.

**Case though XML**

There is an answer in `magento2/module-cms`.

Basically, there is responsible configuration for that:

```
<virtualType name="CmsGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

I didn't find a usage of `CmsGirdFilterPool` but you may try to use [this example of Adminhtml Grid implementation](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html).

**Case thought PHP code**

Also, I found out a simple non-XML way to use "fulltext" filter by customizing method `\Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider::addFilter()`.

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\Component;

use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterApplierInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilterFactory;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

/**
 * Class GridDataProvider
 */
class GridDataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * Fulltext filter
     *
     * @var FilterApplierInterface
     */
    protected $fulltextFilter;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param string                $name
     * @param string                $primaryFieldName
     * @param string                $requestFieldName
     * @param object                $collectionFactory
     * @param FulltextFilterFactory $fulltextFilter
     * @param array                 $meta
     * @param array                 $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        $collectionFactory,
        FulltextFilterFactory $fulltextFilter,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection     = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->fulltextFilter = $fulltextFilter->create();
    }

    /**
     * Add processing fulltext query
     *
     * Some workaround for fulltext search.
     *
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @return void
     */
    public function addFilter(Filter $filter)
    {
        if ('fulltext' == $filter->getField()) {
            $this->fulltextFilter->apply($this->collection, $filter);
        } else {
            parent::addFilter($filter);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        $searchKey = $this->_request->getParam('search');
        if($searchKey) {
               return $this->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter(['filed-1',
                                        'filed-2',
                                        'filed-3'],OR More,
                                   [['eq'=>$searchKey],
                                    ['like'=> '%'.$searchKey.'%'],
                                    ['like'=> '%'.$searchKey.'%'], 
                                    OR More values])
                     ->load()->toArray();
        } else {
              return $this->getCollection()
                          ->load()->toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i`ve not been able to solve it yet, therefore, i'm still using the xml configurations to create the grids. But the addFilter() is something I didn't find yet, i'll definitely have a look at it!

Comment: Sure! You are welcome! Feel free to edit the answer to keep it actual or to correct.

Comment: search filter is still not working